# Url pathname issue in Ajax Post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

In development I make an Ajax post which works in development. However when I put it on the Test server it doesn't work because IIS has assigned the application a subfolder, and this is missing in my development environment.
I have found work around (see below) but I am the first to admit this should not be the solution, as I have to remember to call a function for the url everytime I make an Ajax call.
There must be a better way.
However the code will show you what I am fixing;

```
function OperationsManagerFlagClickFunc(userId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: GetUrl("/Users/UpdateOperationsManagerFlag"),
        type: "POST",
        data: { "userId": userId },
        success: function (data) { }
    });
}

function GetUrl(path) {
    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    if (pathArray[1] === "ITOC")
        return "/ITOC" + path;
    else
        return path;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your javascript in .aspx file, you can generate url like this:

```
function OperationsManagerFlagClickFunc(userId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<%= Url.Action("UpdateOperationsManagerFlag","User") %>",
        type: "POST",
        data: { "userId": userId },
        success: function (data) { }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that. I have to make the controller parameter = "Users" but apart from that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a variable defined separately, like siteUrl, that will hold your site's url, with different values on the 2 servers?
Then just do:

```
url: siteUrl + "/Users/UpdateOperationsManagerFlag"
```